# BI Publisher and SQL Developer Data Display Issue

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

i have a Complex SQL(Tuned to perfection ) , which runs in 11 sec in SQL Developer and produce 51489 records . when i upload this SQL in BIP data Model . it is taking 43 sec to display the data in HTML Format .

is this Delay in BIP HTML is due to Table Rendering Time and huge Amount of Data ? or can it be optimized ?

Answer (score 0):

I only display 500 rows in BIP and it can take up to 20 seconds so I feel like your time is reasonable.